# How to persist a key-value map for fast lookup?

Tags: java

I want to create a hashmap kind of thing for fast lookup between IDs and assigned names.

The number of entries will be a few hundred thousand. Thus I don't want to keep everything in memory. Anyhow, as performance counts in the process, I don't want to make database queries for each ID.

So, what are my chances? How could I get fast lookups on large datasets?

Comment: When you neither want to have everything in memory nor a disk save, would you rather like some magic storage? Hint: Use a "least recently used"-cache in memory and a disk storage for persistence.

Comment: a few hundred thousand is really too much to keep in memory? With current standards it doesn't sound that big to me......but I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm fine with disk storage, but not in a database. I thought there would maybe be some kind of framework like `lucene` that could provide fast lookups.

Comment: Basically you are describing a good old fashioned lookup table here. And there is only place to stick those for optimal performance: in memory. Memory is cheap by the way.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search found these:

Production-ready:

- [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) - I can personally recommend this. It's the successor to JDBM, if you found that one while googling.
- [Chronicle-Map](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-map/)
- [Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/)

Probably nor production-ready, but worth looking at:

- https://github.com/aloksingh/disk-backed-map
- https://github.com/reines/persistenthashmap

Answer (score 1):

Well there are couple of solutions in my mind !

1) Go for `lucene` -> store in files

2) Make `view`s in the database -> store in database

So its upto you for which you go for !!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement a few years back and was avoiding using databases thinking it would have highlook up times. Similar to you I had large set of values so could not use in memory datastructures. So I decided to sequentially parse the filesystem. It was a bit slow, but I could do nothing about it.

Then I explored more on DBs and used DB for my application, just to test. Initially it was slower compared to filesystem. But after indexing the table and Optimizing the database. It proved to be atleast 10-15 times faster than file system. I cant remember the exact performance results but it took just 150-200 ms to read data from a large dataset(around 700 mb of data-size on file system), whereas the same for filesystem was 3.5 seconds.

I used DB2 database, and [this guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27011444) for performance tuning of DB2

Besides once the DB is setup, you can reuse it for mutiple applications over the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking fast solution. Answer `in-memory database`

Redis, Memcached, Hazelcast, VoltDB etc.

Comment: Op said `The number of entries will be a few hundred thousand. Thus I don't want to keep everything in memory` , I think this would eat up a lot of memory if the data set is so large